# Eclipse- JDK not found

Tags: eclipse, windows-7, java

I have downloaded JDK 7 and Eclipse Helios, but when I open Eclipse, I get the following error

```
A java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development kit (JDK) must be available in order 

to run Eclipse. No Java virtual machine was found after searching the following locations:

 C:\eclipse\jre\javaw.exe javaw.exe in your current PATH
```

I have tried to put the exact path of JDK bin folder in eclipse.ini file but it didn't work

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin
```

Can somebody tell me what is the reason behind this issue and how can I solve it.

Comment: what does `java -version` say in the command prompt? Where is eclipse installed?

Answer (score 14):

When I had this problem, I solved the following way (I have Windows 7):

1. Right click on the Eclipse icon in your desktop.
2. Properties
3. Target: C:\eclipse\eclipse.exe -vm C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_32\jre\bin\javaw.exe

   3a (if your jdk is installed in a path like "Program Files"): C:\eclipse\eclipse.exe -vm "C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_32\jre\bin\javaw.exe"

Comment: I don't know why we must explicit pass VM parameter to eclipse to make it work in win 7, but this is the only working way :) The evironment parameter setting is not enough

Comment: @verdana I just tried it on Win7. Adding jdk bin dir to the PATH does work. Try procmon to see why yours is not found.

Answer (score 4):

In your `eclipse.ini` file you need to specify the path to the Jave executable, not just the `bin` directory, as described in [the Eclipse wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini). For example, like this:

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin\javaw.exe
```

Answer (score 3):

Set environment variable `Path`.

```
Path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin
```

Comment: No. You have to set Environment variable (Right mouse click on + properties + ..) http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=njsjWfwPZ2g

Comment: A little late to the party. But I just wanted to say I had the same JNI error and in my case it was that I had downloaded the wrong JDK. Also I was pointing to the wrong program files folder.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because you haven't downloaded Oracle... I had the same issue.

Comment: I have downloaded the JDK from Oracle site. Now what I have to download

Answer (score 0):

I think that eclipse needs to read the file Java, but it does not know where it is located. I normally specify the PATH variable when I install a Java SDK. I think you need to to this, too since it complains about "your current PATH".

Oracle tells you how to do this:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7

From the desktop, right click the Computer icon.
    Choose Properties from the context menu.
    Click the Advanced system settings link.
    Click Environment Variables. In the section System Variables, find the PATH environment variable and select it. Click Edit. If the PATH environment variable does not exist, click New.
    In the Edit System Variable (or New System Variable) window, specify the value of the PATH environment variable. Click OK. Close all remaining windows by clicking OK.

C:\Program Files\Java

Comment: This works, but it is much more elegant to set it in eclipse.ini, as PATH setting is global for the all user apps (at least). Quite often you have different programs requiring different java versions and single global java might not cut it.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem today after installing eclipse on a new PC with an up-to-date 64-bit JRE (on Windows 7 x64). Ajusting the PATH Variable as suggested resulted in the JNI file not found error.

The problem was that I was using a 32-bit eclipse with a 64-bit java runtime. On another computer there was an old 32-bit JRE installed, so the 32-bit eclipse was working. After uninstalling the 32-bit JRE, eclipse stopped working with the same error as above.

What I learned from this:

- Even though java is cross platform, there still is a difference between 32 and 64 bit versions
- Java JRE and the eclipse version have to match (32 or 64 bit) to run properly
- Consequently, it might be necessary to install both - the 32 and 64 bit JRE, depending on the software used
- When updating Java, one always has to update both versions of JRE
- Adding the JRE folder to the PATH is not necessary, it doesn't fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

Yeah,
Even i faced the same problem and found out a solution.
First check whether you have installed Java Jdk . If yes then proceed....
Then go to C:\ then Program Files and look for java and in there you will find a Jdk file open it then copy the bin file and go to your adt-bundle-windows-x86_64 and place the bin file under Eclipse . Hope this works for you and happy developing ;)

Answer (score 0):

Because Eclipse and JDK "installing time" is very short. I think a clean solution will save your time.

```
1/ The first, JDK and Eclipse should be the same "bit" (Eclipse 32 bit go with JDK 32bit, and 64 bit so on). I think nowaday computers with large memory and modern 64 bit OS should choose the 64 bit pair.
2/ Remove all JDK version in your PC, check if its done by: Open CMD, type "java" and enter, if there is no application run, you done.
3/ Install JDK (assume JDK 8 64 bit)
4/ Download the rights version of Eclipse (zip)(assumse you download 64 bit version)
5/ Just extract eclipse and run it.
```

---

Eclipse is just a portable software which packaged in a zip, don't waste your time to fix a wrong installation.
Hope this help.

Answer (score -1):

E-Riz's comment worked for me, I just had to make sure I put the command at the top of the ini file.

Inside the eclipse directory you will have an eclipse.ini, at the very top of the ini file past the directory path

```
-vm
C:\.....\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin\javaw.exe
```

Comment: Actually [eclipse.ini wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM) says that it must come after all eclipse specific options (although it worked for me at the top too).

Comment: **DO NOT** follow this advice. As @chukko says, read the wiki page for specific instructions about the format of eclipse.ini

Answer (score -3):

You don't need to edit any path. Here is what you do.

1. Open the Eclipse folder
2. Search "javaw" in the search.
3. Copy "javaw" and paste it into the folder.
4. Open Eclipse.
5. Enjoy!

I don't know why you guys keep talking about the path. It has nothing to do with it. The dialogue box said is was only searching that folder for the javaw program.