# How to install eclipse for php on windows7

Tags: php, eclipse

I want to install Eclipse for PHP.

I download Eclipse "PDT 3.0.2 w/Eclipse indigo" to my folder "c:\eclipse" and extract the zip file.

I am also download "jre-6u37-windows-94.exe" and install it successfully.

The problem is when I try to run the file eclipse.exe I get error.

**A Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK) must be available in order to run Eclipse. No Java virtual machine was found after searching the following locations:
c:\eclipse\jre\bin\javaw.exe
javaw.exe in your current PATH**

The jre installed in directory.

**c:\Program Files (x86)\java\jre7\bin**

What should I do for running successfully the eclipse.

this is my confog.ini

```
#This configuration file was written by: org.eclipse.equinox.internal.frameworkadmin.equinox.EquinoxFwConfigFileParser
#Mon Jun 11 14:17:27 IDT 2012
org.eclipse.update.reconcile=false
eclipse.p2.profile=pdtProfile
osgi.framework=file\:plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.7.2.v20120110-1415.jar
equinox.use.ds=true
osgi.bundles=reference\:file\:org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.0.200.v20110815-1438.jar@1\:start
org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator.configUrl=file\:org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator/bundles.info
eclipse.product=org.zend.php.product
osgi.splashPath=vplatform\:/base/plugins/org.zend.php
osgi.framework.extensions=
osgi.bundles.defaultStartLevel=4
eclipse.p2.data.area=@config.dir/../p2
eclipse.application=org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench

org.zend.php.customization.site.url=http\://downloads.zend.com/studio-eclipse/updates-extra/9_0,http\://downloads.zend.com/studio-eclipse/updates/9_0
```

should I add the line `-vm Path=c:\Program Files(86)\Java\jre7\bin` to top file ?

Because it is not working

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11590355/eclipse-jdk-not-found

Comment: Make sure the bitsize matches - you need to match the bitsize of your java (32 bit in your example) and Eclipse (needs to be 32 bit, but 64 bit is available).

Comment: where can I find the  "environment variable Path." ?

Comment: Have you settled the path? You can find either your path is set or not by command 'javac' on cmd.If this command doesn't recognize by system then yor need to set the path

Comment: please check wether javaw.exe file is present at your this location c:\eclipse\jre\bin\javaw.exe

Comment: you down Reputation but you don't suggest solution.

Comment: I am not the one who down vote you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet you that this conflict is due to installation of conflicted java setup
You just need to confirm that you are using 32-bit or 64-bit Windows and then install  java according to your OS requirement.
**32-bit java for 32-bit OS and 64-bit java for 64-bit OS.**
You will surely get rid from this problem :)
Another alternative is to re-run the JRE setup. It typically installs a default JRE by placing java.exe, javaw.exe, etc. in your system folder. That would place the executables in your path, which should be sufficient, based on the note in the error message that it searched your path for javaw.exe
if you are still sure that you have installed the right setup then try to set the path by using this command
**set PATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.6.0_03\bin ;%PATH%**

Answer (score 2):

As "PDT 3.0.2 w/Eclipse indigo" for Windows is only available for 32bit platform, **you need to download a 32bit JRE** as well to make it run on 64bit Windows platform. Don't forget to make JRE visible for Eclipse by either editing eclipse-php.ini or adding  "-vm " as argument to a shortcut pointing to eclipse-php.exe.

More details here:

http://blog.lopau.com/eclipse-pdt-32-bit-on-windows-7/

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse can't find your java installation.

Follow this steps:

- control panel -> view advanced system settings
- On tab advanced -> environment variables -> system variables -> click new button
- in the dialog  that appears -> variable name -> enter **JAVA_HOME**
- in the same dialog -> variable value -> enter **c:\Program Files (x86)\java\jre7**
  and click ok to close dialog.
- In system variables search for variable named **Path**. If it doesn't
  exist create it with new button.
- If there was a Path variable append **;%JAVA_HOME%\bin** at the end of
  the content in the variable value field.
- If you have to create the Path variable enter **%JAVA_HOME%\bin**
- Click OK to close edit system variable dialog
- Click OK to close enviroment variables
- Open windows command prompt and type **echo %JAVA_HOME%.** The answer
  should be c:\Program Files (x86)\java\jre7 If this is not the case
  check previous steps.
- Start eclipse.